# How to read an existing file, read it into database, and combine different databases

Tags: python, mysql

I am attempting to read two massive files into code. They have a linked primary key (it's database files). I don't know what the best method of reading them in is, if I should use Python to load it into a tuple or list versus if I should use Embedded SQL in Python to load it?

Assuming the answer is Embedded SQL, I'm having a lot of difficulty in the code to actually load a file into a table. In the past I've only ever done it with a online file. If it's a local file, how do I load it in?

I am unsure of how to do this. I used something similar to

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="yourusername",
  passwd="yourpassword"
)
```

but that makes no sense given the fact this is a local file.

Comment: I am unclear what your trying to do, at first sight it seem like you wish to load 2 files (csv?) from your pc to a mysql server also on your pc? if so a few lines from each file as text in the question would help  together with a note any transformations required. AND what do you mean by combine databases?